# Generic parameter 'Output' could not be inferred

Tags: swift, combine

When I add `print("value == \(value)")` in `Just{}`, I get a compile error:

> Generic parameter 'Output' could not be inferred

My code:

```
import Foundation
import Combine
class JustViewObservableObject: ObservableObject {
    
    var cancellable: AnyCancellable?
    
    struct Student: Decodable {
        let name: String
    }
    
    let json = """
    [{
    "name": "李雷"
    }]
    """
    init() {
        let publisher = PassthroughSubject<String, Never>()
        publisher.flatMap { value -> Just in
            print("value == \(value)")
            return Just(value.data(using: .utf8)!)
                .decode(type: [Student].self, decoder: JSONDecoder())
                .catch { _ in
                    Just([Student(name: "无名氏")])
                }
        }
        publisher.send(json)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace `Just` in the closure signature with the full name of the return type, that is, the type of this expression:

```
Just(value.data(using: .utf8)!)
    .decode(type: [Student].self, decoder: JSONDecoder())
    .catch { _ in
        Just([Student(name: "无名氏")])
     }
```

Because your closure has more than one statement after adding the print, Swift refuses to infer its return type.

However, since you used quite a lot of combine operators here, the full type is quite long:

```
Publishers.ReplaceError<Publishers.Decode<Just<JSONDecoder.Input>, [JustViewObservableObject.Student], JSONDecoder>>
```

It would be more practical to use `eraseToAnyPublisher`, so that the type just becomes `AnyPublisher<[Student], Never>`. You can also replace the `.catch { _ in Just(...) }` with `replaceError(with:)` (note a small difference is that the `Student` object is created immediately if you use `replaceError`, but I don't think that matters unless your real code is different):

```
publisher.flatMap { value -> AnyPublisher<[Student], Never> in
    print("value == \(value)")
    return Just(value.data(using: .utf8)!)
        .decode(type: [Student].self, decoder: JSONDecoder())
        .replaceError(with: [Student(name: "无名氏")])
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
```

Personally, I don't see a point in doing the decoding with Combine. I would just use a `do...catch`:

```
publisher.map { value -> [Student] in
    print("value == \(value)")
    do {
        return try JSONDecoder().decode([Student].self, from: value.data(using: .utf8)!)
    } catch {
        return [Student(name: "无名氏")]
    }
}
```